# Storing Friends in Database for Social Network

Tags: mysql, sql, database, facebook, social-networking

For storing friends relationships in social networks, is it better to have another table with columns `relationship_id, user1_id, user2_id, time_created, pending` or should the confirmed friend's user_id be seralized/imploded into a single long string and stored along side with the other user details like `user_id, name, dateofbirth, address` and limit to like only 5000 friends similar to facebook?

Are there any better methods? The first method will create a huge table! The second one has one column with really long string...

On the profile page of each user, all his friends need to be retrieved from database to show like 30 friends similar to facebook, so i think the first method of using a seperate table will cause a huge amount of database queries?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with PHP, MySQL (specifically) OR Codeigniter...

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here.  I don't understand the second option. Have you worked with databases before? Are you asking a fundamental question about database relationships?  What exactly is your question. Please take it out of the context of the social network and stuff.  Make it generic, but give short, clear examples.  That'd be good.  :)

Comment: Trevor: For the second option, I meant to say in the main table storing data about the user, to include a new field that contains all the user-ids of that particular user's friends, for example `1101-1102-1104-1211` if that user are friends with users whose user ids are `1101, 1102, 1104, 1211`. When i need to retrieve the user ids, I will explode the string into an array and use them

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most *proper* way to do this would be to have the table of Members (obviously), and a second table of Friend relationships.

You should never *ever* store foreign keys in a string like that. What's the point? You can't join on them, sort on them, group on them, or any other things that justify having a relational database in the first place.

If we assume that the Member table looks like this:

```
MemberID int Primary Key
Name varchar(100) Not null
--etc
```

Then your Friendship table should look like this:

```
Member1ID int Foreign Key -> Member.MemberID
Member2ID int Foreign Key -> Member.MemberID
Created datetime Not Null
--etc
```

Then, you can join the tables together to pull a list of friends

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Member m
RIGHT JOIN Friendship f ON f.Member2ID = m.MemberID
WHERE f.MemberID = @MemberID
```

(This is specifically SQL Server syntax, but I think it's pretty close to MySQL. The `@MemberID` is a parameter)

This is always going to be faster than splitting a string and making 30 extra SQL queries to pull the relevant data.

Comment: Random Note: If your friendship graph is undirected (i.e. in this example implementation you could exchange `Member1ID` with `Member2ID`), then you may want to introduce a constraint `Member1ID < Member2ID`.  This way you can check if two members are friends with a single lookup `(lowerID, higherID)`, instead of requiring two lookups `(lowerID, higherID) OR (higherID, lowerID)`.  It also implies that a member cannot be friends with him/herself.

Answer (score 0):

Separate table as in method 1. 
method 2 is bad because you would have to unserialize it each time and wont be able to do JOINS on it; plus UPDATE's will be a nightmare if a user changes his name, email or other properties.

sure the table will be huge, but you can index it on Member11_id, set the foreign key back to your user table and could have static row sizes and maybe even limit the amount of friends a single user can have. I think it wont be an issue with mysql if you do it right; even if you hit a few million rows in your relationship table.